# Can I have an Azure website and webjobs in the same deployment slot with common app setting names but with different values?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-webjobs

Like many basic configuraitons I've got an Azure website and several associated webjobs sharing a deployment slot.  I would like to define an application setting, e.g. `MySetting` that both the web app and webjobs can refer to, but I want to have *different* values for that setting - one value specific for the web app and one for the webjobs.  AND, while I do understand that I can put MySetting in the web app's Application Settings blade and then override that setting in the webjobs by creating a MySetting entry in the webjob's `app.config`, I do *not* want to store secrets in application files.

What options do I have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your App and WebJobs are hosted in the same Azure Web App (or slot), there is no way to give them different values for the **same** Azure App Setting key. You will need to use different App Setting keys, e.g. `FOO` vs `MYWEBJOB_FOO`.

Comment: Thank you David.  I think the approach I'll take is to decouple the webjobs from the web app and associate them with a new, "blank" web app (for convenience of deployment).  Then I'll have the app settings blade of the new web app and I can use the same key name with a different value.

Comment: Certainly, that will work if you can decouple them. And it is true that if you have multiple WebJobs, deploying them via a dummy Web App makes things easier.